# Latex Overfull /hbox when inserting table. Cannot change width without changing table structure

Tags: latex

When I insert my table into latex I get an overfull /hbox error and cannot figure out how to change the width without changing the structure of my table. The code of my table follows as such:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c||}
 \hline
 Function() & Computational Cost (Gas)& USD  Equivalent \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
Total Deployment & 8342204 & 1.195559526  \\ 
 \hline
Security Registration & 3849155 & 0.5516400614 \\
 \hline
\textit{MintSecurity} & 76293 & 0.01093389983 \\
 \hline
\textit{TransferFrom} & 55146 & 0.007903226248 \\
 \hline
\textit{Swap} & 89343 & 0.0128041552 \\ 
 \hline
\textit{AddLiquidity} & 185368 & 0.02656593847 \\
 \hline
\textit{Remove Liquidity} & 67137 & 0.009621711468 \\ [1ex]
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: "overfull hbox"  is often just a warning, not an error. That said, could we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: As said in the other comment, please do add a [mre]. To answer your question, it is vital to know the exact page geometry of your document, which will depend on the class and packages you use. The code you show perfectly fits into a default article, no overfull box...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/submission-format-for-ipvc-cybersec22/ckfvrxdpyrnb -- I used this template.

Comment: @Ameer the link to the template is not helpful, since we don't know how you modified it or where you inserted the table. Please take a look at the link provided by Robert and samcarter regarding the minimal reproducible example. You have a better chance to get (meaningful) help if you make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the template you are using, tables are set in a smaller font size, so the problem is solved automatically if you use a `table` environment instead of `center`.

In addition, you can use the `tabularray` package, so the table will automatically match the text width:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{||c X[c] c||}
 \hline
 Function() & Computational Cost (Gas)& USD  Equivalent \\
 \hline\hline
Total Deployment & 8342204 & 1.195559526  \\ 
 \hline
Security Registration & 3849155 & 0.5516400614 \\
 \hline
\textit{MintSecurity} & 76293 & 0.01093389983 \\
 \hline
\textit{TransferFrom} & 55146 & 0.007903226248 \\
 \hline
\textit{Swap} & 89343 & 0.0128041552 \\ 
 \hline
\textit{AddLiquidity} & 185368 & 0.02656593847 \\
 \hline
\textit{Remove Liquidity} & 67137 & 0.009621711468 \\
 \hline
\end{tblr}%
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]